# One BigQuery table in same dataset for each integration with same product in Stitch

Tags: google-bigquery, etl, branch.io, stitch

We are using the setup of BigQuery, Stitch and Branch.io. In Branch.io we generate deep links which are shared from our app. The data from Branch.io we the ETL with Stitch to our data warehouse at BigQuery.

We want to have several tables from Branch.io, one with data on clicks on deep links, and one with data on installs from deep links.

This works fine: We set up two webhooks in Branch.io and manage to ETL that data to BigQuery.

HOWEVER, we do not want this data to be in separate datasets. We only manage to get two separate datasets with one table each called "data".

We want one dataset, let's say "deep_links" with two tables, "installs_" and "clicks_". We would also like each of those two tables to be replicated with all data for each day. So that the data for today (2017-11-20) will end up in the tables "installs_20171120" and "clicks20171120".

Is this possible?

Comment: If you wish to send clicks and installs to different locations, you can set up two different webhooks with two different destination URLs.

Comment: @AmrutaDeshmukh That is not what I want, I want to send clicks and installs to the same location (BigQuery), in the same dataset "deep_links", with two different tables.

Comment: I am not sure of the setup required on BigQuery end.